# Angular: bracket syntax doesn't work when providing input values?

Tags: angular, typescript, property-binding

Using bracket syntax to provide input value doesn't work.  However, when I remove the brackets, its does.  Why is this?

Child component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `<p>My name is {{name}}</p>`,
})
export class ChildComponent  {
  @Input() name;
}
```

Parent component template - this doesn't work, why??:

```
<p>Parent component</p>

<app-child [name]='Peter'></app-child>
```

Parent component template - this work's:

```
<p>Parent component</p>

<app-child name='Peter'></app-child>
```

Comment: Because `[name]="'Peter'"` gets interpolated, and without `name="'Peter'"` does not. Since you're passing something static, no need to use brackets. When deciding if you need to use brackets, just think if you need to have the value interpolated. Also, when passing a boolean, if you don't use brackets it'll be passed as a string, just something to keep in mind.

Comment: Makes sense.  But to further ask, wouldn't an interpolated string simply just return another string?  For example, in any template file, I can add {{'test123'}} and though the expression within the double brackets gets interpolated, it still renders test123.  Also, why don't the Angular docs mention this?

Comment: @lightspeed `[name]='Peter' ` means you have a variable named `Peter` and you want to bind the value of it, this is why it doesn't work. as alphapilgrim mentioned you need to change it to `[name]="'Peter'"`

Comment: It does make mention to this in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax), also I'm just making an assumption here but traditionally `{{}}` is actually JS-land. Where you can run all the JS type things, and brackets is strictly for evaluation of primitives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Parent component template - this doesn't work, why??:
>
> Parent component
>
> `<app-child [name]='Peter'></app-child>`

Here, angular looks for a variable named *Peter* which doesn't exist. If you change it to

```
<app-child [name]="'Peter'"></app-child>
```

it will work as expected.

Also, from the Angular [docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#one-time-string-initialization):

> You should omit the brackets when all of the following are true:
>
> 1. The target property accepts a string value.
> 2. The string is a fixed value that you can put directly into the template.
> 3. This initial value never changes.